# Windows 10 freezes every 30 minutes

Tags: windows-10, drivers, ssd, freeze, dell-optiplex

I own a [Dell Optiplex 9020](http://www.dell.com/nl/bedrijven/p/optiplex-9020-desktop/pd) (the small one) with a Intel Core i7 processor and a 120GB SSD with a fresh install of Windows 10.

The problem is that Windows freezes after about 30 minutes of running very smoothly. If I wait, it shows a blue screen with the `CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED` error:

[image: CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED]

Eventually the PC will reboot and display the following:

[image: Windows 10 harde drive not found error]

Pressing either F1 or F5 will boot Windows again as if nothing every happened.

I've tried re-installing Windows two times. I've tried installing different drivers from the Dell and Intel websites. I've also ran the [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) software for about 4 hours with no results. Eventually I ran out of patience and stopped the test at 50%. The BIOS is also up-to-date.

These are some recent activity logs (in dutch, sorry):

```
Waarschuwing    28-9-2015 00:00:01  DeviceSetupManager  201 Geen
Waarschuwing    28-9-2015 00:00:01  DeviceSetupManager  202 Geen
Waarschuwing    28-9-2015 00:00:01  DeviceSetupManager  200 Geen
Waarschuwing    28-9-2015 00:00:01  DeviceSetupManager  202 Geen
Fout    28-9-2015 00:00:01  Eventlog    1101    Gebeurtenissen verwerken
Kritiek 27-9-2015 23:59:57  Kernel-Power    41  (63)
Fout    28-9-2015 00:00:01  EventLog    6008    Geen
Fout    27-9-2015 22:58:16  DeviceSetupManager  131 Geen
Waarschuwing    27-9-2015 22:58:11  DeviceSetupManager  201 Geen
Waarschuwing    27-9-2015 22:58:11  DeviceSetupManager  202 Geen
Waarschuwing    27-9-2015 22:58:11  DeviceSetupManager  200 Geen
Waarschuwing    27-9-2015 22:58:11  DeviceSetupManager  202 Geen
Fout    27-9-2015 22:58:11  Eventlog    1101    Gebeurtenissen verwerken
Kritiek 27-9-2015 22:58:07  Kernel-Power    41  (63)
Fout    27-9-2015 22:58:10  EventLog    6008    Geen
Fout    27-9-2015 22:46:00  DeviceSetupManager  131 Geen
Fout    27-9-2015 22:44:05  DeviceSetupManager  131 Geen
Waarschuwing    27-9-2015 22:43:59  DeviceSetupManager  201 Geen
Waarschuwing    27-9-2015 22:43:59  DeviceSetupManager  202 Geen
Waarschuwing    27-9-2015 22:43:59  DeviceSetupManager  200 Geen
Waarschuwing    27-9-2015 22:43:59  DeviceSetupManager  202 Geen
Fout    27-9-2015 22:43:38  Service Control Manager 7031    Geen
Fout    27-9-2015 22:43:38  Service Control Manager 7031    Geen
Fout    27-9-2015 22:43:38  Service Control Manager 7031    Geen
Fout    27-9-2015 22:43:38  Service Control Manager 7031    Geen
Fout    27-9-2015 21:54:35  DeviceSetupManager  131 Geen
Fout    27-9-2015 21:54:35  DeviceSetupManager  131 Geen
Fout    27-9-2015 21:52:39  DeviceSetupManager  131 Geen
Waarschuwing    27-9-2015 21:52:34  DeviceSetupManager  201 Geen
Waarschuwing    27-9-2015 21:52:34  DeviceSetupManager  202 Geen
Waarschuwing    27-9-2015 21:52:34  DeviceSetupManager  200 Geen
Waarschuwing    27-9-2015 21:52:34  DeviceSetupManager  202 Geen
Fout    27-9-2015 21:52:34  Eventlog    1101    Gebeurtenissen verwerken
Kritiek 27-9-2015 21:52:30  Kernel-Power    41  (63)
Fout    27-9-2015 21:52:34  EventLog    6008    Geen
Fout    27-9-2015 20:49:27  DeviceSetupManager  131 Geen
Fout    27-9-2015 20:49:26  DeviceSetupManager  131 Geen
```

The critical `Kernel-power` errors are my fault. This is when my computer freezes and I manually shut off the PC and turn it on again. I know this is not good for the PC, but hey, it's better then throwing it out of the window.

The last thing that maybe is worth telling: after installing windows, I'm missing the `SM BUS Controller driver` as shown on [this page](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/inf/sb/CS-013541.htm). But after downloading the chipset utility the yellow exclamation mark will disappear.

This problem is driving me crazy and I'd love to hear your ideas/suggestions.

**Edit:**
Activity logs after removing all partitions, creating a new one and installing Windows 10 on it:

[image: logs]

Comment: seems a hdd problem, did you do a clean install and full format of your SSD (deleting all partiotion) or install inside a partition? Do you have another hdd attached to your PC? Have a look at Event Viewer maybe you can find a critical error there, and try to see on memory dump

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Only have one SDD attached to my PC. I did indeed remove all partitions and then created a new one for Windows. I'm going to reïnstall windows now and keep you informed if I see any weird logs after this.

Comment: @emirjonb I've updated my post with the latest activity logs after re-installing Windows 10. I haven't seen the `Apllication error` before. Also, these look like pretty much errors and warnings. Is this normal?

Comment: During the boot time is quite normal to have some warning and errors. What about that warnings with source:disk what is written there? Do you experience the blue screen again after 30 minutes?
You can do a check using 3rd part soft like CrystalDiskInfo with a much detailed output as the answer suggested below

Comment: @emirjonb I got rid of most of the errors by updating windows and drivers and restarting. I think (almost know for sure) the `disk (ID 153)` and `storachi (ID 129)` warnings are causing the freeze. I don't get to see a blue screen anymore, the PC just freezes which forces me to turn it off manually. Running the HDtune software atm.

Comment: ok than `storahci` must be a short name for storage AHCI, where AHCI is a controller hdd standard. You can change the AHCI on BIOS enable or disable you can give it a try (I think you are familiar with Bios). You can try a new searching campaign for AHCI and SSD error on windows 10 if you still can't see any result after changing this option on bios

Comment: @emirjonb The problem is solved, the SDD was indeed damaged, I have a new one :-) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your drive has SMART support (It most likely does), run a test and get the results. It sounds like the hard drive is faulty.

Post the results here if you are unsure whether the test results are a pass or not.

Comment: I just ran the built-in Windows memory test and drive analysis. No problems detected... unfortunately. I don't know where to find the SMART support.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that Windows doesn't have a way to see SMART information built in, you can use a tool like http://www.hdtune.com/download.html, you want to look at the 'Health' Tab. If the Health status is anything but 'ok', the disk is the culprit.

Comment: The tests turned out OK on everything. But my PC was freezing multiple times (for about 10-20 seconds). In the error log I find multiple `disk` and `storachi` warnings (about 300-400!)

Comment: Thankfully, you can test if the hard drive really is the problem very easily, you just need to swap the drive out for another and do a fresh install.

Comment: The problem is solved, the SDD was indeed damaged, I have a new one :-) Thanks for your help